# Failed to install turicreate by anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, turi-create

Got modulenotfounderror when I try to import turicreate in my python file.
I've installed Anaconda and use the following statements to install turicreate:

```
conda create -n turi python=3.7 anaconda

source activate turi

pip install turicreate
```

got following error after install:

```
Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - turicreate

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

Environment:

Macos:10.13.6
python:3.7.3
conda:4.1.10

some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import turicreate as tc
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

import sys
sys.path.append("..")
customers=pd.read_csv('bijing/testdata/data/recommend_1.csv')
transactions=pd.read_csv('bijing/testdata/data/trx_data.csv')
print(customers.shape)
customers.head()
```

Comment: Have you installed it? I didn't see any relevant commands

Comment: I think I failed to install turicreate by ```pip install turicreate```

Comment: When did you execute this command, you should install it after activation of `trui`

Comment: Still got error after activate turi```Solving environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - turicreate
```

Comment: You can update your question and post more about the error

Comment: I download anaconda in python 3.7 version, not sure is that a problem?

Comment: That is indeed a problem, it's not supported.  check this https://github.com/apple/turicreate#system-requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create a new environment named `trui` with a specific version of Python=3.6 
$ conda create -n trui python=3.6
#Activate the environment - trui
$ conda activate trui
$ pip install -U turicreate
```

Then you do everything under this environment.

Comment: I have reinstalled anaconda in version2.7 and run with python=2.7 successfully.

Comment: @PoppyBee Great!